# Javascript stop setInterval

Tags: javascript

```js
if (document.case.display.value.length  >16 &&  document.case.display.value.length < 21) {

      Notiflix.Notify.Info('Because you have a lot of charatchers font size is smaller');
      document.getElementById("display").style.fontWeight = "550";
      document.getElementById("display").style.fontSize = "2em";
} else if (document.case.display.value.length > 20) {
    var str = document.case.display.value.length
    Notiflix.Notify.Warning('Max characters you can see is 25 ');
    Notiflix.Notify.Failure('Number of your characters' + str);

    document.getElementById("display").style.fontWeight = "500";
    document.getElementById("display").style.fontSize = "1.5em";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("display").style.fontWeight = "500";
    document.getElementById("display").style.fontSize = "2.5em";
}}

window.setInterval(function(){
testLength();
}, 100);
```

Notiflix is a JavaScript  library for notification.
I have a display who font go down if have so much characters and i set time every 0.1 second he check number of characters. If number is higher than 16 he put a notification.
But he put every 0.1 second notification i want only one time/s. Do you have idea who can "block " this line of code for 10 second and after that read this without moving settimer down.

Sorry about bad English.
Any information will help me

Comment: When you want only delay in code execution, you should use `setTimeout`

Comment: Never post code as an image. Just paste it in your post.

Comment: As @KrystianG said, better post code here, even better would be to use markdown also

Comment: @Diminik Matis i want all time this fuction work so i set setInterval .Do you have idea who i can stop one line of code when he done one time but other line of function working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try storing your setInterval() in a variable and calling it only when required. Else, you can stop that using that variable name.

```
let myInterval;

function start(){
    myInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
        testLength();
    }, 100); 
}

function stop(){
    clearInterval(myInterval); 
}
```

P.S: I would also like to advice on using **onChange** eventListener for checking test length rather than setInterval.

**Update: Alternate method**

You can also try removing setInterval thing and adding something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".digit")
  console.log("numbers", numbers);
  numbers.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', testLength))
});
```

Comment: Thanks but dont work dont give me error in console or something like thaht but still don't work https://codepen.io/TheLexa/pen/zgRZjb there is code pen full code

Comment: @volimtvojukevu After running your code, I found that Notiflix is undefined. How do I get it running so that I can test that?

Comment: this is full web site code this code work conslose 0 error try to enter 16 number and see

Comment: check the updated alternate method in my answer above. It should work

Comment: Thank you soo much if u need help about anything msg me on instagram _lexa01 thanks a lot :D